# Prestashop after submit return page html

Tags: prestashop

Hello I develop a module under Prestashop 1.6 and I am blocked on the submission of a form.

I add in my module a form with the hook "DisplayAdminOrderContentShip" which retrieves a tpl hook_button.tpl which displays my form (button)

[relance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bX6v.jpg)

here is my tpl:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <p>Export commande mecalux</p>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <p>Permet de relancer l'export vers Mecalux de la commande</p>
    <form method="POST" action="#">
        <button type="submit" value="1" id="exportordersubmit" name="exportordersubmit" class="btn btn-default pull-right">
            <i class="process-icon-refresh"></i> {l s='Relancer l\'export' mod='exportorders'}
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is my function:

```
public function hookDisplayAdminOrderContentShip($params)
{
    $order = new Order(Tools::getValue('id_order'));
    $status = (int)Configuration::get('EXPORTORDERS_STATUS_TRANSFERED_TO_WMS');
    $statusError = (int)Configuration::get('EXPORTORDERS_STATUS_CMD_ERROR');

    if (Tools::isSubmit('exportordersubmit')) {
        if (isset($order) && (int)$order->valid == 1) {
            if ($order->current_state != $status && $order->current_state != $statusError) {
                return;
            }
            if (!$order->valid) {
                return;
            }

            $customer = $order->getCustomer();

            $deliveryAddress = new Address($order->id_address_delivery);
            $id_country_delivery = $deliveryAddress->getCountryAndState($order->id_address_delivery);
            $iso = new Country();

            $userXml = [
                'id_client' => $customer->id,
                'email' => $customer->email,
                'livraison' => $deliveryAddress,
                'country_code_delivery' => $iso->getIsoById($id_country_delivery['id_country'])
            ];

            $dateOrder = new DateTime($order->date_add);

            $orderXml = [
                'id' => $order->id,
                'sorCode' => $order->reference,
                'payment' => $order->payment,
                'date' => $dateOrder->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s') . 'Z',
            ];
            $result = $this->fileXml($userXml, $orderXml, $order->getProducts());

            if ((int)$result === 1) {
                $order->setCurrentState($statusError, (int)$this->context->employee->id ? (int)$this->context->employee->id : 0);
                $html = [
                    'message' => $this->displayError('Erreur de transmission au WMS'),
                ];
            } else {
                if ((int)$order->current_state !== (int)$status) {
                    $order->setCurrentState($status, (int)$this->context->employee->id ? (int)$this->context->employee->id : 0);
                    $order->wms_transfered = 1;
                    $order->save();
                    $html = [
                        'message' => $this->displayConfirmation('Transmise au WMS'),
                    ];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $this->context->smarty->assign(
        array(
            'alert' => $html
        )
    );

    return ($this->display(__FILE__, 'views/templates/hook/hook_button.tpl'));
}
```

and when I click here is the result of my page:

[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkXzs.jpg)

normally it should return an alert in the order detail page (admin) I do not see where my problem comes from have any idea?
Thank you for your help.

[fetch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNWqj.jpg)

Comment: try with fetch instead of display `return ($this->context->smarty->fetch(__FILE__, 'views/templates/hook/hook_button.tpl'));`

Comment: it displays html in order detail (see image)

Comment: did you change the content type of the php file with some `header('Content-type...)` ? somewere before you call `$this->display(......`

Comment: no it is a simple form.

Comment: what solution do I have?

Comment: it's weird, in PS 1.6 to show my TPL in module i use `$this->context->smarty->fetch('mymodule/views/templates/hook/hook_button.tpl')` and it's has always worked, you can try to specify the entire path to your module by usring  `$this->context->smarty->fetch(str_replace('\\', '/', dirname(__FILE__)). '/views/templates/hook/hook_button.tpl')`

Comment: How do I manage the submission of my form?

Comment: by the post process method of the module, it's a function that always called after a form submission, my tip is to download a basic module structure from here https://validator.prestashop.com/generator

Comment: I have the same problem, when I submit I have html that appears

Comment: it's just my opinion but it seems as you have a Content-Type issue in your module, or with the htmlspecialchart decode, try this `$output = $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/templates/hook/hook_button.tpl'); return htmlentities_decode($output);`

Comment: it displays html in the hookDisplayAdminOrderContentShip